# Why is as.integer returning NA in R?

Tags: r, memory, integer

I have noticed that if I have a number larger than 10 digits, the `as.integer` function will return NA.

For example:

```
as.integer(10000000000)
```

will give NA.

Why does this happen? I guess it might have something to do with the storage of integers? How can I work around this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: 32-bit integers,so 2^31-1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the limit for integers by:

```
> .Machine$integer.max
[1] 2147483647
```

Any bigger values will be interpreted as NA

```
> as.integer(.Machine$integer.max)
[1] 2147483647
> as.integer(.Machine$integer.max+1)
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

If you need to handle bigger values, either use `as.numeric` (numerics can handle bigger values than integers) or a package like gmp (Multiple Precision Arithmetic package).

Comment: Note: `gmp::as.bigz(.Machine$integer.max+1)` gives `2147483648`